# Switch com Format no Power BI (DAX)

Tags: formatação, switch, powerbi, dax

boa noite!

Sou nova em DAX e gostaria de uma ajuda para a questão a seguir:

```
Meta Formatada = SWITCH
(KPI.Formatacao
, "Money", FORMAT([Meta],"Currency")
, "Numeric", FORMAT([Meta],"General Number")
               , "Unknown value" )
```

"KPI.Formatacao" é minha "tabela.coluna"
Gostaria de entender se é possível e como posso fazer um switch em cima de uma coluna e não de uma expressão.
Caso seja possível só via expressão, há alguma forma de colocar o texto dessa coluna como medida?

Obrigada desde já.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
Meta Formatada =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE (),
            SELECTEDVALUE('KPI'[Formatacao])="Money",FORMAT([Meta],"Currency"),
            SELECTEDVALUE('KPI'[Formatacao])="Percent",FORMAT([Meta],"Percent"),
            FORMAT([Meta],"Standard")
            )
```